# How to limit permissions of Project Admin in Azure DevOps(ADO)?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, permissions, devops

How can I stop Project Admin to delete a Security group and/or Teams group. Also, how can I stop Project Admin from removing members from a particular custom Security group and/or Teams Group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to limit permissions of Project Admin in Azure DevOps(ADO)?

I am afraid there is no such way to do this at this moment.

According to the document [Project-level groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#project-level-groups):

> **Project Administrators**: Has permissions to administer all aspects of teams and project, although they can't create team projects.

That means that the PA has the highest project-level authority and cannot limit its authority.

As workaround, we could create a new group and set it as member of the Project Administrators group, then we could set the permissions for that group.

Comment: Thanks, that was the conclusion of my research as well but wanted to make sure if I am missing any point here. Thanks for you help.
Do you think you can answer this ?
Thanks, that was the conclusion of my research as well but wanted to make sure if I am missing any point here. Thanks for you help.
Do you think you can answer this ?
Thanks, that was the conclusion of my research as well but wanted to make sure if I am missing any point here. Thanks for you help.
Do you think you can answer my other questions?